# npm install lite-server --save-dev error

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, npm-install, lite-server

I'm trying to use node for the first time in a VS project in windows. I installed node.js, below is the info:

```
node -v 
v8.9.3
npm -v
5.5.1
```

Completed setup in the project using npm init, that seemed to work fine.

npm install lite-server --save-dev  produced the following error:

```
$ npm install lite-server --save-dev
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   win32
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64
```

I don't understand the errors. Help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The error comes from `fsevents@1.1.3`, which is a dependency package of `lite-server`.

`fsevents@1.1.3` only works in macOS. See its [npm info page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fsevents).

> Native access to OS X FSEvents in Node.js
>
> The FSEvents API in OS X allows applications to register for
>   notifications of changes to a given directory tree. It is a very fast
>   and lightweight alternative to kqueue.

Similar issues also apply to other npm packages with such dependency.

---

I am using `npm@5.6.0`, the latest stable release, and tried install on my Windows. The error turns out to a warning and let `lite-server` installed eventually. Anyway, `fsevents` is just an optional dependency.

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\lite-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ lite-server@2.3.0
added 279 packages in 81.466s
```

Comment: For the other readers : the parameter to skip optional dependencies is "no-optional" 
-> npm install --save-dev --no-optional lite-server

Answer (score 1):

I found the fix for Ubuntu 18.04/20.04 after working for whole day. This should work for other Linux distros

1. Run following command  for globally using lite-server

   ```
    sudo npm install lite-server -g
   ```
2. Your package.json file should contain

   ```
    "devDependencies": {
   "lite-server": "^2.5.4"
    }
   ```

and scipt should look like

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "npm run lite",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "lite": "lite-server"
  },
```

3. For development mode run following

   ```
    sudo npm i lite-server --save-dev
   ```
4. Local server could started using npm command

   ```
    npm start
   ```